# For Apple Macs, should I install Anaconda in the Home directory or Applications directory? What are the pros and cons?

Tags: anaconda

I noticed that when I chose the Applications directory option, Anaconda also installed all these extra files besides just the executable program in the Applications folder on my MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

"The executable program" you saw is a drop in the bucket. Anaconda is a distribution of multiple programs and resources that work together. Install it wherever you want, and leave it alone. If you put it in `/Applications`, it will be where the system expects to find applications, and will also be available to any other users with an account on your computer.

I don't see any reason to install it under your home directory, unless the Mac is not your own and you lack administrator permissions. Basically on a single-user machine it doesn't make much difference where you put it.